# Is there a way query the denomination information of a substrate token from the runtime?

Tags: data-analytics

Different substrate chains have different denominations for native tokens.

For example, to get human readable amounts with [Polkadot you have to divide by 1e10, Kusama by 1e12](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info), [Acala by 1e12](https://wiki.acala.network/integrate/integration/protocol-info) etc.

Is there a way to find the denomination by querying the chain itself rather than googling protocol information? In a storage function or the metadata for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PolkadotJS offers it. Simple as:

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

const decimals = api.registry.chainDecimals;
console.log(`Polkadot has ${decimals} decimals`);
// Polkadot has 10 decimals
```